# pandas replace specific string with numeric value in a new column for all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column `message`, and I want to create a column `media` such that if for index x, `df.ix[x][message]=="<Media omitted>"` ,then I want `df.ix[x][media] = 1`

for example for the dataframe:

```
index    message
1        hello
2        <Media omitted>
3        hello
4        <Media omitted>
```

I would get:

```
index    message          media
1        hello             0
2        <Media omitted>   1
3        hello             0
4        <Media omitted>   1
```

I tried to do so only by using a loop, but I'm sure there is a smarter and faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['media'] = (df['message'] == '<Media omitted>').astype(int)
```

**Explanation**

- `df['message'] == '<Media omitted>'` creates a Boolean series.
- `astype(int)` casts the Boolean series as integer type for display purposes.

Comment: If I want to the same for 2 different string values? like for `'<Media omitted>'` and `thisstringtoo` ? I tried with an or operator, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try using `isin`: `df['media'] = (df['message'].isin({'<Media omitted>', 'thisstringtoo'}).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need convert boolean mask to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['media'] = (df['message'] == '<Media omitted>').astype(int)
#very similar alternative
#df['media'] = df['message'].eq('<Media omitted>').astype(int)
print (df)
               message  media
index                        
1                hello      0
2      <Media omitted>      1
3                hello      0
4      <Media omitted>      1
```